# Dynamic date sales

Tags: mysql, sql

I am trying to pull data from two table **campaing** and  **sales** table by joining on item_num key.

```
With campaing as 
(Select distinct item_num,campaing_id,campaing_name,campaing_start_date,campaing_end_date
from Campaing_event 
where camping_start_date > to_date ('20190101', 'yyyymmdd')
)
```

All the above campaing has different start and end data, How do I get sales data for these campaing from sales table using the above campaing start and end date.

Thanks in Advance.

Comment: please provide sample data and expected output

Comment: You tagged mysql but use oracle's `to_date()`. Which is your dbms?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I would guess your `sales` table has a `sold_on` date column. If that's the case, then your query should look like:

```
with
c as (
  select distinct 
    item_num, campaing_id, campaing_name, 
    campaing_start_date, campaing_end_date
  from campaing_event 
  where camping_start_date > to_date ('20190101', 'yyyymmdd')
)
select c.*, s.*
from c
join sales s on s.item_num = c.item_num
 and s.sold_on >= s.campaing_start_date
 and s.sold_on <= s.campaing_end_date
```

Answer (score 0):

Since you didn't specify the columns in the SALES table I used SALES_DATE for the column.
You can use this query modifying it as per your  schema:

BASED ON EXISTS

```
With campaing as 
(Select distinct item_num,campaing_id,campaing_name,campaing_start_date,campaing_end_date
from Campaing_event 
where camping_start_date > str_to_date ('20190101', '%Y%m%d')
)
SELECT * FROM SALES T1 WHERE 1=1
AND EXISTS(
    SELECT 1 FROM CAMPAING T2
    WHERE T1.ITEM_NUM = T2.ITEM_NUM
    AND T1.SALES_DATE BETWEEN T2.campaing_start_date AND T2.campaing_end_date
)
```

BASED ON JOIN

```
With campaing as 
(Select distinct item_num,campaing_id,campaing_name,campaing_start_date,campaing_end_date
from Campaing_event 
where camping_start_date > str_to_date ('20190101', '%Y%m%d')
)
SELECT * FROM SALES T1 join CAMPAING T2
    on T1.ITEM_NUM = T2.ITEM_NUM
    AND T1.SALES_DATE BETWEEN T2.campaing_start_date AND T2.campaing_end_date
```